# Soapclient and the transfer of user Kerberos authentication

Tags: php, kerberos, soap-client

I am consuming services through Soapclient with a Kerberos authentication.

A website is hosted in Server A and accessed through Kerberos authentication
and web services is hosted in Server B and again accessed through Kerberos authentication.

Web service responds with different personal content based on the authenticated user. And same Active Directory is used for both Server A and Server B Authentication.

The server A consumes service from Server B and post-process the response before rendering it to the browser. The user browser has access to all the contents in server A and we do have access to the `WSDL` on server B.

The problem is with `SoapClient` as it is not successfully transferring User Kerberos authentication to Server B Service.

We have the following error message:

> SOAP-ERROR: WSDL analysis: impossible to load from 'https: //***********/index.php? Wsdl ': Can not load an external entity "https: // **** ******* / index.php? Wsdl"

When `Kerberos authentication` is temporarily disabled then the Service can be accessed via SoapClient.

`Server A` is under IIS with PHP 7 installed.

To Impersonate User, we set up Kerberos Double Hop for the website.

Is it possible to transfer Kerberos authentication information with `SoapClient`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible. See the official PHP bugtracker here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52231